# Getting weird number when trying to read a number from file

Tags: c++, char, int, ifstream, cstring

I'm trying to read a number from a text file, and I'm not allowed to use a binary file.
I've tried two methods to do this, and both return a strange result.

The first method:

```
    char *theNumber; 
    int i = 0;
    while(data>>text)
    {
        theNumber[i] = text;  
        i++;
    }
```

returns some weird accented characters.
The second

```
int theNumber;
while(data>>text)
{
     theNumber = text; // I tried theNumber<<text; as well
}
```

When I cout the result of this one it returns some big number when the text file contained 123.

---

```
string filename;
    char text;
    int p; //first prime number
    int q; //second prime number
    unsigned long long toBeEncrypted; 

    cout<<"Enter name of file to encrypt: ";
    cin>>filename;
    ifstream data;
    ofstream encryptedData;
    encryptedData.open("RSA_cipher.txt");


    cout<<"Please enter two prime numbers:"<<endl;
    p = getPrime(1);
    q = getPrime(2);

    //doing stuff with file
    int theNumber;
    data >> theNumber;
    //int i = 0;
    /*while(data>>text)
    {
        theNumber[i] = text;  
        i++;
    }*/cout<<theNumber;
```

...//other stuff unrelated to the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
char *theNumber; 
int i = 0;
while(data>>text)
{
    theNumber[i] = text;  
    i++;
}
```

Has **Undefined Behavior**, because you are using `theNumber[i]` to access an array which you haven't even allocated. You should have done:

```
 char theNumber[255]; // Buffer size depends on the particular application
 int i = 0;
 while(data>>text)
 {
     theNumber[i] = text;  
     i++;
}
```

The second attempt:

```
theNumber = text;
```

May or may not work, depending on how you defined `text`. This is impossible to answer without knowing the definition of `text`.

Anyway, if you want to read in a number from an input stream, just do:

```
int number;
data >> number;
```

**UPDATE:**

In the last code snippet you updated, the `data` stream is constructed, but never open. It is not associated to any file. Therefore, attempting to read from that stream won't succeed, and nothing will be stored into `number` (which is uninitialized).

```
ifstream data;

// data is not associated to any file after construction...

int theNumber;
data >> theNumber;
```

Comment: I mistyped that, I meant that with 1 = sign. That code wasn't c/p'd on and I manually typed it in sorry. I tried doing your method with `data>>number` and it still prints out a long number

Comment: @ArcaneExplosion: Prints out when? How do you store the number? Are you still using `text` and `theNumber`? What is the definition of `text`? There are a lot of things I can't see from your question's text. Try to put there a short, complete example of the code you are using. Otherwise, I'll be solving problems you don't have and not solving those you have

Comment: No I'm not using the whole while loop and I just do `data >> theNumber` and I print it out immediately after for error checking purposes. Also in the second example `theNumber` is an `int`

Comment: @ArcaneExplosion: So what is the content of the file you're reading from?

Comment: Just a simple number. "123" as I stated in the above.

Comment: I couldn't c/p my entire program, but I could put in the relevant function where the problem is occuring. All the variables used are local to that function.

Comment: OH MY GOD, how did I overlook this THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: @ArcaneExplosion: That happens ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This **does not** create storage for your number.

```
char *theNumber;
```

It's a pointer.  It points somewhere arbitrary, since you haven't assigned an address to it.

Try this.

```
char theNumber[10];  // Whatever size you need.
```

Or this.

```
int theNumber;
```

Comment: The second example I used used int theNumber, and that doesnt seem to work as well. The other returns ASCII

Answer (score 0):

You didn't allocate any memory for `char *theNumber;`.
The `theNumber` points to a random location and you are printing random characters